# How to take a phone number with a plus and bracket and just return the numbers?

Tags: c#, regex, phone-number

I have a simple problem I have a phone like this: +1 (123) 123-1234 and I want to just take the numbers out of that string using regex.

Answer (score 13):

This will strip out an non-numeric characters:

```
string input = "+1 (123) 123-1234";
string digits = Regex.Replace(input,@"\D",string.Empty);
```

Comment: Won't that remove all the digits?

Comment: \D (capital D) means non-digits
\d (lower case d) means digits

Comment: Only thing I'd change is Regex.Replace(input, @"\D", string.Empty), but I'm anal like that.

Comment: @Jerret Meyer, good point, that does clarify the intention. Code updated.

Answer (score 6):

Using RegEx is one solution.  **Another way would be to use LINQ** (provided you are using .Net 3.5)

```
    string myPhone = "+1 (123) 123-1234";
    string StrippedPhone = new string((from c in myPhone
                                       where Char.IsDigit(c)
                                       select c).ToArray());
```

The end result is the same, but I think LINQ offers some advantages over RegEx in this case.  First, readability.  The RegEx requires you to know that "D" means Non digit (compared to Char.IsDigit())- there is confusion about that already in the comments here.  Also, I did a very simple benchmark, performing each method 100,000 times.

LINQ:  127ms

RegEx: 485ms

So, at a quick glance, it seems like LINQ out performs Regex in this situation.  And, I'd argue it is more readable.

```
    int i;
    int TIMES = 100000;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    string myPhone = "+1 (123) 123-1234";

    // Using LINQ            
    sw.Start();
    for (i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
    {
        string StrippedPhone = new string((from c in myPhone
                                           where Char.IsDigit(c)
                                           select c).ToArray());
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Linq took {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    // Reset 
    sw.Reset();

    // Using RegEx
    sw.Start();
    for (i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
    {
        string digits = Regex.Replace(myPhone, @"\D", string.Empty);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("RegEx took {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: True, and +1 for that, it's quite nice and elegant, but the OP may not be able to use .NET 3.5 at this point ;)

Comment: And that's a good point to - I forget that not everyone is using 3.5; I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: also, just to further emphasize your point, "D" means "NON-digit", not digit.. so yeah, Char.IsDigit() seems more readable to me too.
The regex solution is concise though. :)

Comment: Wow, impressive. Regex performance can be improved using RegexOptions.Compiled, but running a quick test shows that even then it's only marginally faster then LINQ. I learned something today. Thanks Rob P!

Answer (score 2):

```
string digits = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", String.Empty);
```

Comment: \D (capital D) means non-digits

Answer (score -2):

Why not just do a replace?

```
string phoneNumber = "+1 (123) 123-1234";
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.Replace("+", "");
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.Replace("(", "");
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.Replace(")", "");
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.Replace("-", "");
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: Because that way you've just created 6 strings. http://bit.ly/fi0Rq A String object is called immutable (read-only) because its value cannot be modified once it has been created. Methods that appear to modify a String object actually return a new String object that contains the modification. If it is necessary to modify the actual contents of a string-like object, use the System.Text.StringBuilder class.

Comment: And? Premature optimization (except in the 2% of cases) ... you know the deal.  Honestly why is a simple (if crude answer) worth 2 down votes?

Comment: +1: it's not. It's correct, and the 'more ideal' solution will float up higher.

Comment: You still won't handle any other out-of-place characters (such as [",<,>,#,etc...]).  It is not simple (you have to do a Replace for every Non-Digit character to be correct), which makes it needlessly verbose. At least put the characters to ignore in a list and iterate over the list. At that point, why not just iterate over the string and append the characters that *are* digits to a result string?

Comment: @C.Ross, indeed I do, and I didn't down vote, just supplied a comment. To be fair, the OP asked for a RegEx, and to quote Raymond Chen, "you have a problem, and you try and solve it with a RegEx, now you have two problems".